# How use SSH with VBscript

Tags: ssh, vbscript

I have to write a script which does commands in SSH and if possible catch some returns.

I searched, but didn't find direct support between SSH and VBscript.

I founded Chilkat, but I'd need to pay and because of that I can't use it.

Comment: [Software recommendations are off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: googling "vbscript ssh" finds other options.

Comment: I don't want a Software Recommendation, if I wanted a software I would be using Putty or some software like that.

I want know a external library or something like it.

Comment: That falls into the same category.